# How can I make this image be positioned below the text?

Tags: html, image, css

I do not know how to get this image below the text.

```
    <h1>OUR Services</h1>
    <p>DESIGN CONTRACT
         Examples

  Starting from $1,800…

    It all starts with your vision. We develop that vision and help you 
    shape it into reality. That development starts with a plan. Our Design 
     Contracts are detailed, comprehensive and collaborative. <img 
     src="design.png" alt="house example"></p>
    </div>
```

Floating, align middle  is what I've tried.

I just want the image below the text! Maybe it thinks I'm asking for an arm and 2 legs.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQLra.jpg

https://codepen.io/admitdefeat/pen/BEyMzK

Answer (score 0):

just define the attribute `display`

```
img{
  display: block;
}
```

**OR**

change your markup structure

```
<p>DESIGN CONTRACT
Examples

Starting from $1,800…

It all starts with your vision. We develop that vision and help you shape it into reality. That development starts with a plan. Our Design Contracts are detailed, comprehensive and collaborative. </p>
 <img src="https://tinypng.com/images/example-shrunk.png" alt="house example" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple and not that complicated i think tables are a good option

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=Coral>
<TABLE BORDER=0 ALIGN=CENTER>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><FONT SIZE=5>OUR Services</FONT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>DESIGN CONTRACT Examples Starting from $1,800... it all     starts     whit your<br>vision.We develop the vision and help you shape it into     reality.That<br>development starts with a plan. Our Design Contracts are detailed.</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><IMG     SRC="C:\Users\marti\Desktop\Html\f43fc3ced583705f36926b6c9ebf3222--pearler-beads-fuse-beads.jpg"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>comprehensive and collaborative</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with an image, and it works perfectly. I didn't change your main code, all I changed was the image. Hope this helps you in some way!

```css
body {
    color: #454547;
 font-family: "Basier";
 font-size: 1.2rem;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height: 1.9rem;
}
html { 
  background-color: #fdfaeb;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.en{ 
  background: url(summer.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container{    
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
 box-sizing: inherit;
    width: 37%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #fdfaeb;
    color: #2f3036;
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    display: block;
}


@font-face { 
 font-family: "Basier";
 src: url("basiersquare-regular-webfont.ttf");
}
header {
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 140px;
    float: left;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0 px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Basier";
    color: #2f3036;
    background: #fdfaeb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #F4D03F;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #F4D03F;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #fdfaeb;
    color: #2f3036;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Basier";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F4D03F;
    background: #fdfaeb;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>CLT Designs Home Remodeling & Renovations</title>
 <link href="hoise.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link href="designs.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 
<img class="logo" src="https://www.flowersbylindsey.com/catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/image/po_gallery/po-gallery-square-200_.png" alt="logoclt">﻿
 
 
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="thahomepage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ABOUT.html">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="Services.html">Services</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="Design.html">What is Design + Build?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Process</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
 <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 
  <div>
  <div class="container">
  
  <h1>OUR Services</h1>
  <p>DESIGN CONTRACT
Examples

Starting from $1,800…

It all starts with your vision. We develop that vision and help you shape it into reality. That development starts with a plan. Our Design Contracts are detailed, comprehensive and collaborative. <img src="https://www.flowersbylindsey.com/catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/image/po_gallery/po-gallery-square-200_.png" alt="house example"></p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you you are magical, do you have any advice or good tutorials on ow to get better at position and alignment? I have a hard time getting this in the place i want them too.

Comment: Hey, your welcome, I learned mostly from w3Schools(https://www.w3schools.com), and I just watch a lot of YouTube tutorials. And I recommend using 'position: absolute' for positioning. Have a good day!